# How to connect sql server for a query in ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, database, ionic-framework

I would like to connect my ionic V3 application to SQL Server database, where should I put the config object and how can I use the database in my application?
What I need is to display the result from the query as table or grid in the homepage.

In summary:

1. Connect the application to the database
2. Make some query
3. Display the result of the query in the homepage view

Comment: Hi Abdulaziz! Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: You could simply google it. take a look at this link: https://ionicframework.com/blog/creating-an-ionic-app-with-mysql-and-backand/

Comment: This is for ionic v1, so it won't work

Comment: Did you try [this?](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/way-to-use-cordova-plugin-sqlserver-problem/118783/4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this in tow ways :

1- using sqlite :

```
 SqlServer.init("ipAddress","dbName","dbUser","password",result => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result))})}
```

2- use this tutorial ([here](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-http-to-fetch-remote-data-from-a-server-in-ionic-2/))
this can be used for fetch data from API's (REST API for example ) of to build your own sql query and use it as API